# Xcode 9 beta – Unsupported pixel format [Vuforia ARKit]

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, vuforia, xcode9-beta, arkit

I have an project iOS within Unity that accesses the device's camera for Vuforia.

At some point within the App, ARKit will also be accessed. However, when switching from Vuforia to ARKit, I get this error;

```
//[Sensor] Unsupported pixel format: 875704438
//AR FAIL
```

This only happens, when Vuforia boosts up first, and then ARKit. Alone, if ARKit is only used, then it works fine.

This only seems to be the case with iOS11 - Beta 3. Worked fine on Beta 2, but I can't downgrade.

Any reasons as to what may be causing this?